# Gatsby plugin image cannot read property 'startsWith'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

Didn't find this on the site but I did find an [open bug on Github](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/30143) and the only resolution, at time of writing, is to use `GatsbyImage`. Learning to convert a Gatsby project from 2 to 3 I've installed [gatsby-plugin-image](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image/) and am converting a component that uses a non-changing image in a Hero component and per the docs `StaticImage` should work.

The old component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import Image from 'gatsby-image'


const query = graphql`
{
  person: file(relativePath: {eq: "person.png"}) {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
  }
}
`

const Hero = ({ showPerson }) => {
  const { person } = useStaticQuery(query)

  return (
    <header className="hero">
      {showPerson && <Image fluid={person.childImageSharp.fluid} className="hero-person" />}
    </header>
  )
}

export default Hero
```

new component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'

import personImage from '../assets/person.png'

const Hero = ({ showPerson }) => {
  console.log(personImage)
  return (
    <header className="hero">
      {showPerson && <StaticImage src={personImage} className="hero-person" alt="person image" />}
    </header>
  )
}

export default Hero
```

When I log the asset I get (no issues with my file path):

```
Hero.js:7 /static/person-c7035ca6b9544d80f8f0626ea3e22ace.png
```

but the log renders:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2430 No data found for image "undefined"
Image not loaded /static/person-c7035ca6b9544d80f8f0626ea3e22ace.png
```

and in the terminal I get:

```
"gatsby-plugin-image" threw an error while running the preprocessSource lifecycle:

Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
```

With Gatsby image `StaticImage` is there a way to render an image that doesn't change in a component without using `GatsbyImage`?

Comment: also getting this issue after upgrading to gatsby `^3.2.0-next.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [docs about the new Gatsby Plugin Image](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/):

> **Restrictions on using `StaticImage`**
>
> The images are loaded and processed at build time, so there are
> restrictions on how you pass props to the component. The values need
> to be statically-analyzed at build time, which means you can’t pass
> them as props from outside the component, or use the results of
> function calls, for example. You can either use static values, or
> variables within the component’s local scope. See the following
> examples:

So, `<StaticImage>` component can't handle props nor function calls to receive the image. In your case, this should work:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'

const Hero = ({ showPerson }) => {
  return (
    <header className="hero">
      {showPerson && <StaticImage src={`../assets/person.png`} className="hero-person" alt="person image" />}
    </header>
  )
}

export default Hero
```

Due to the similarity of your `v2` approach, I would suggest using `<GatsbyImage>` rather than `<StaticImage>`, check it out to see if it fits your requirements.

For the migration issues, [Gatsby has developed a codemod](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/image-migration-guide/#how-to-migrate) that handles all the GraphQL queries and the "old" `gatsby-image`s, changing the needed queries and components. Once you've installed the plugins, just run:

```
npx gatsby-codemods gatsby-plugin-image
```

With that, the issue should be gone. If not, you can follow similar stack traces at:

- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/30143
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/30030

It seems that the issue is related to the `3.2.0-next.0` version so another option is trying to downgrade (or upgrade if possible).

Comment: StaticImage is perfectly fine here :) GatsbyImage is about programmatically generated data, e.g. if the image comes from the frontmatter. In this case the person has a path to a file, it's a one time use, so StaticImage is the way to go

Comment: Yes in this use-case I think you are right but the fact `StaticImage` can't get outer `props` leads me to use the `GatsbyImage` due to the similarity from the `v2` approach.

Comment: What downvote? Indeed, I upvoted... Does the use of `GatsbyImage` fixed your issue? You can try to use directly `<StaticImage src={`../assets/person.png`}` if you want to keep the StaticImage

Comment: The issue isnt with using `GatsbyImage` it's with `StaticImage` not working at all and any attempt, per the docs, the resulting error is the same. I get I can, and at the moment till `StaticImage` is resolved, will use  `GatsbyImage` the docs outlining it and the issue should be raised in hopes it helps others and to see if anyone is able to get `StaticImage` to work and if so what are the use cases for it.

Comment: Yes I will leave my answer here to to help someone in the same situation. I assume that the issue will be removed shortly in the new releases :) I'm glad you finally bypass it

Comment: This isn't an issue in the package but user error. So using any version is fine

Comment: It's not in the roadmap of Gatsby's allowing to use props in StaticImage to bypass the current restrictions? Anyway, thanks for the useful insights, as usual @LekoArts